# Proper syntax for using variables in a SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, variable-assignment, substitution

I have a script which queries an Excel spreadsheet and returns values.
I run the code below as it is with a sample spreadsheet 'DB2.XLSX', in the same folder.

With the line at comment #2, it returns the output as

> First Name is: Nicole and Last Name is: Lee

But if I replace it with line at comment #1, the output is

> First Name is: [NO RECORDS] and Last Name is: [NO RECORDS]

Why is the value substitution for the variable `CustID` not working?

Code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Randomize
Dim conn, rst, query, fname, lname, CustID
CustID = 000276

'1 
query = "SELECT * FROM [Report$] WHERE [ID]= '" & CustID & "'"
'2    
query = "SELECT * FROM [Report$] WHERE [ID]= '000276' "

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=db2.xlsx;" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes';"

Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open query, conn

If rst.EOF Then
    fname = "[NO RECORDS]"
    lname = "[NO RECORDS]"
Else
    fname = rst("First Name").Value
    lname= rst("Last Name").Value
End If

MsgBox("First Name is: " & fname & " and Last Name is: " & lname)
```

Comment: Padding error? Try with `CustID = "000276"`

Comment: Exactly. `CustID = 000276` is the same as `CustID = 276` (leading zeroes are not preserved for numeric values). Hence the SQL query becomes `SELECT * FROM [Report$] WHERE [ID]= '276'` and thus doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: Also - left-padding numeric values with zeroes is a recipe for all sorts of data-exchange problems.  At the very least, put an alpha character in front.

Comment: How do I mark these answers as 'accepted' ? I searched around and according to this, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work 
there should be a checkmark next to answers, but I don't seem to see any.